# Openstack: login as admin and retrieve server data from different tenants via python

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, devstack

I'm writing some cron job in python for Openstack that should read server ids from a database and then get the servers from the API by using the python-novaclient.

In pseudo code things should work like this:

```
session = login_to_keystone(user="admin", password="something") #or use a token
nova_client = get_nova_client(session)

#the servers array holds dictionaries with server, user and tenant ids as strings
# e.g. {"server_id": "1-2-3", "tentant_id": "456", user_id: "11111-2222"}
for server in servers:
   server_obj = nova_client.servers.get(server.server_id)
   ...do stuff with server_obj (read data from it, delete,...)...
```

What I've come up with is the following, but it's not right as I get a EndpointNotFound exception. I'm using Devstack with Juno.

```
from keystoneclient.v2_0 import client as keystone_client
from keystoneclient import session
from novaclient import client as nova_client

#the url is the admin endpoint
keystone = keystone_client.Client(token="my-admin-token",
            auth_url="http://192.168.1.1:35357/v2.0",
            endpoint="http://192.168.1.1:35357/v2.0")

key_session = session.Session(auth=keystone)
nova = nova_client.Client(2, session=key_session)

#let's assume the servers array is already populated
for server in servers:
    server_obj = nova.servers.get(server.server_id) #Exception happens here
```

I need to run this as admin as servers can belong to any tenant and they might even be deleted by the cron job.

Thanks for any help!

**UPDATE:**
The information I need was that I can use the admin tenant for retrieving all servers (regardless of their owner). This allows me also to use the publicURL.

My current solution looks like this:

```
from keystoneclient.auth.identity import v2
from keystoneclient import session
from novaclient import client as nova_client

auth = v2.Password(auth_url="http://192.168.1.1:5000/v2.0",
                   username="admin",
                   password="my_secrete",
                   tenant_name="admin") # the admin's tenant

auth_session = session.Session(auth=auth)
nova = nova_client.Client(2, session=auth_session)

for server in servers:
    ... do stuff like nova.servers.get("some id")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get a list of servers from all tenants, you need to perform two tasks:

1. Log in as a user with admin privileges, and
2. Tell the Nova API that you want a list of servers for all tenants.

### Logging in as an admin user

It looks like you're trying to use the `admin_token` defined in `keystone.conf` for authentication.  This may work, but this mechanism is meant primarily as a means of bootstrapping Keystone.  When interacting with the other services, you are meant to log in using a username/password pair that has been defined in Keystone with admin credentials.  I think that what @anoop.babu has given you will work just fine:

```
>>> nova = nova_client.Client('2', USERNAME, PASSWORD,
                              PROJECT_ID, AUTH_URL)
```

Where:

- `USERNAME` = `admin`
- `PASSWORD` = `password_for_admin_user`
- `PROJECT_ID` = `admin`
- `AUTH_URL` = `http://your_api_server:5000/v2.0`

We can test this client out using something like:

```
>>> nova.hypervisors.list()
[<Hypervisor: 2>]
```

That tells us we've authenticated successfully.

### Listing all servers

If we simply called `nova.servers.list()`, we are asking for a list of Nova servers owned by the `admin` tenant, which should generally be empty:

```
>>> nova.servers.list()
[]
```

In order to see servers from other tenants, you need to pass the `all_tenants` search option:

```
>>> nova.servers.list(search_opts={'all_tenants':1})
[<Server: cirros0>]
```

And that should get you where you want to be.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have given auth_url as your endpoint. endpoint is actually the **publicURL** of the service.
You can find the publicURL using the below CLI Command

```
nova endpoints
```

and check for keystone details.

You can also get an authenticated keystone object using below api version without using endpoint,

```
import keystoneclient.v2_0.client as keystone_client
keystone = keystone_client.Client(auth_url = my_auth_url , username = my_user_name , password = my_password , tenant_name = my_tenant_name )
```

And create a session object as below,

```
from keystoneclient import session
key_session = session.Session(auth=keystone)
```

An alternate and simplified approach to get nova client authorized without keystone is,

```
from novaclient import client as nova_client
nova = nova_client.Client('2', USERNAME, PASSWORD, PROJECT_ID, AUTH_URL)

server_obj = nova.servers.find( name=my_server_name )
```